# different config for each host using ansible

Tags: ansible

I have the following standalone.xml configs ->
- standalone.xml (dev)
- standalone.xml (staging)
- prod-standalone1.xml (production cluster 1)
- prod-standalone2.xml (production cluster 2).
- prod-standalone3.xml (production cluster 3).

Trying to use ansible to deploy each one of these configs based on the cluster/host that they are on.  These configs go in the standard standalone config directory -> flyway/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [Splitting Out Host and Group Specific Data](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data) in ansible docs. You can have configuration file for each of your host in group_vars folder.

If the host is named ‘foosball’

```
 /etc/ansible/host_vars/foosball
 [ raleigh]
 127.0.0.1
 [webservers]
 127.0.1.2
```

and in groups ‘raleigh’ and ‘webservers’, variables in YAML files at the following locations will be made available to the host:

```
/etc/ansible/group_vars/raleigh
/etc/ansible/group_vars/webservers
```

Comment: your solution looks ok. My concern is why you have "standalone_config_path" variable in host_vars instead of group_vars. In your question, don't you wanted to group it based on environments(dev/staging/prod)? Take a look at playbook best practices for organizing your variables http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#group-and-host-variables

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution is to add group_vars/host_vars and then use those to determine which files to copy over.  The other solution is to make a single standalone.xml file which would be located in templates directory and you could then manipulate the values in the standalone.xml file via variables which would be generated and then copied over.

```
dev (host file) ->
192.168.3.1

staging (host file) ->
192.168.3.2

prod (host file) ->
192.168.3.3

/etc/ansible/group_vars/all ->
wildfly_home: /usr/local/wildfly/
wildfly_config: "{{ wildfly_home }}standalone/configuration/"

/etc/ansible/host_vars/192.168.3.1 -> (contents)
standalone_config_path: dev/

/etc/ansible/host_vars/192.168.3.2 -> (contents)
standalone_config_path: staging/

/etc/ansible/host_vars/192.168.3.3 -> (contents)
standalone_config_path: prod/


roles/my-role/files/dev/standalone.xml
roles/my-role/files/staging/standalone.xml
roles/my-role/files/prod/standalone.xml

roles/my-role/tasks/main.yml -> (contents)
copy: src={{ standalone_config_path }}standalone.xml dest=dest={{ wildfly_config }}
```